# Method undefined for type

Tags: java, methods

Could somebody help me out with the following code? I'm getting the error

> The method originDistance is undefined for type Point

what can I do to fix it?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(1, 1);

        System.out.println(p1.originDistance());
    }

    int x;
    int y;

    public double originDistance() {
        double dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        return dist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Point p1 = new Point(1, 1);
```

Change to

```
Test p1 = new Test(1, 1);
```

and add

```
public Test(int x, int y)
{
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}
```

Test is your class not Point so this needs to be changed also you need to add a constructor to initialize your x and y variables.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I needed to match my method with my class.

Answer (score 2):

The `originDistance` method does not belong to the `Point` class, it belongs to your `Test` class. If you want to use it on your point you can make these changes:

- Change it to a static method
- Receive a point as a parameter

It will look something like this:

```
public static double originDistance(Point point) {
    double dist = Math.sqrt(point.getX() * point.getX() + point.getY() * point.getY());
    return dist;
}
```

And then in you change your main to call the new method:
System.out.println(originDistance(p1));

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
public Test()
{
    Point p1 = new Point(1, 1);

    System.out.println(this.originDistance(p1.x, p1.y));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

public double originDistance(int x, int y) {
    double dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    return dist;
}
```

You were trying to access the method from the `Point` Object but it is actually defined in your `Test` class.

Also, your method would not work as the `x` and `y` values where never instanciated.

The identifier of your current class is `this` this is why I used the keyword before calling originDistance. Some people find it more clear, but it would also works just calling the method without prefix and wouldn't break any convention.

Comment: This won't work unless originDistance is a static method.  Also he would need a point class.

Comment: You're right, I wrote to fast, Edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is defined in the Test class, not in the point class.
you need to either rename your class or create a Test instance to call your originDistance() method

```
Test p1 = new Test(1,1);
System.out.println(p1.originDistance());
```

Look into the java trails for really good documentation and helpful tips on learning java.

Comment: This won't work without constructor.

Comment: ah right.. i didn't try to fully compile the code, just looked at the specific problem he was asking about, but you're right there are a few issues here. also where is the import statement for the Point class?